# My node app on ibm cloud keeps crashinng

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node app on IBM cloud and it keeps crashing every time and most of the time it's not running, I've even increased the memory per instance to one gb, How do I diagnose where the issue is? Here is my manifest.yml. So I'm in a situation whereby I have to continually check the app and do a manual restart

---

```
applications:
- instances: 1
  timeout: 600
  name: TicketSokoChatbot
  buildpack: sdk-for-nodejs
  command: npm start
  memory: 1024M
  random-route: true
```

here is the error:
`an instance of the app crashed: Instance never healthy after 1m0s: Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused; process did not exit`

Comment: Have you checked the logs in the dashboard? What is the error you are seeing? Post it here

Comment: @data_henrik here is the error   

`an instance of the app crashed: Instance never healthy after 1m0s: Failed to make TCP connection  to port 8080: connection refused; process did not exit`

Comment: Show the code where the PORT is configured. It seems that Cloud Foundry is trying to perform a health check, but just a guess.

Comment: Does it run fine local?

Comment: yes, I tried setting the env by installing cfenc as an npm package but the problem still persists

Comment: Someone has downvoted your question.  My guess for the downvote is because it doesn’t contain enough information to help diagnose the problem.  Have a look at this page for hints: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  For example, when you say it is running, are you able to access you app via it’s url?  How are you checking the app and restarting it?  What packages are you installing?  Can you include more of your log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running on cloud foundry, the port is set for you.  You must use that port which you can find in the environment variable `PORT`, e.g.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

If the port isn’t the cause of the issue, the next thing you could try is changing the [health check timeout](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html#health_check_timeout).

If this doesn’t work for you, the cloud foundry docs provide information on [Troubleshooting](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html), in particular take a look at the section [App Fails to Start](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html#start).  Here is one of the debug steps listed in the cloud foundry documentation:

> Find the reason app is failing and modify your code. Run `cf events
>   APP-NAME` and `cf logs APP-NAME --recent` and look for messages similar
>   to this:
>
> `2014-04-29T17:52:34.00-0700   app.crash          index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: app instance exited, exit_status: 1`
>
> These messages may identify a memory or port issue. If they do, take
>   that as a starting point when you re-examine and fix your application
>   code.

After trying all of debug steps, if you are still unable to fix your problem add more information to your question with what you have tried.

I recommend that anyone building cloud foundry apps gets acquainted with the developer focused cloud foundry documentation [Deploying and Managing Applications](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/index.html#deploy).